# Changing from 4 to 3 columns with omega with Susy fails

Tags: sass, susy-compass

This is certainly easiest to show with some code:

```
.container{
    .gallery {
        ul {
            @include clearfix;
        }
        li {
            @include span-columns(1,4);

            &:nth-child(4n) {
                @include omega;
            }
        }
    }

    @include at-breakpoint($large-columns) {
        .gallery {
            li {
                @include span-columns(1,3);

                &:nth-child(4n) {
                    @include remove-omega;
                }
                &:nth-child(3n) {
                    @include omega;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm starting out with 4 columns with the 4th being omega, then I want to change over to 3 columns, with the 3rd being omega. The correct elements are floated left/right correctly, but every 4th gets a wrong margin-right...

Am I doing this right? Or rather, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for reading,
/Andy

Comment: can you show working code on codepen or jsfiddle?

Comment: Um, not really since it's depending on Susy... Basically, the output from the preprocessor is wrong. You can see it here: http://codepen.io/andymoreno/pen/EcKHC

Comment: I've tested your codepen, it seems to be working fine. Initially it'll be 4 columns, but when the min-width reach 59em it'll become 3 columns. Is that how you expect it to work?

Comment: Look at the margin-right of 4n elements inside the mediaquery, that's what I'm asking about above; margin-right being wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your question is misleading because we don't know the value of `$large-columns`. I assumed that value might be `59em 3` - but that works perfectly. It seems the value is actually just `59em` - which is causing your problem.

If you set a breakpoint without a column-count, Susy calculates a new context based on your `$column-width` and `$gutter-width` settings. That doesn't cause any problem for `span-columns(1,3)` because you override the global context with an explicit one (3). But `remove-omega` also needs to know the context (in order to apply gutters) and you don't pass one - so it uses the global context.

You have two options:

1. You can change the breakpoint: `at-breakpoint(59em 3)`
2. You can pass an explicit context: `remove-omega(3)`.

Comment: $column-width = 4em, $gutter-width = 1em, $large-columns = 12. Sorry, I didn't realise that those values would make any difference for the calculation to work? Should work for any values?

Comment: Um, I'm not sure I understand... Am I not explicitly removing the omega on 4th items above?

Comment: You are removing omega, but you aren't understanding the way context affects calculations. Your breakpoint is setting the context to 12 columns, but `span-columns(1,3)` overrides that with a context of 3. You need to make sure `span-columns` and `remove-omega` are getting the same context. Either `span-columns(4)` and `remove-omega` (both will assume the global context of 12), or `span-columns(1,3)` and `remove-omega(3)` (both use 3). Or you can change the breakpoint to set a context of 3 globally with `at-breakpoint(59em 3)`. `remove-omega` adds a gutter, relative to context.