# How to apply span-column within at-breakpoint with Susy?

Tags: responsive-design, susy-compass

Now, I am almost having a responsive header as my original question was [How to make a header responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048134/how-to-make-a-header-responsive) . Still I am bit stuck with having the width of elements right.

I am using the following Susy-Compass setup:

```
.mod-header
  @include container ($total-columns, $mobile-to-medium, $medium-to-large)  
  border: 2px red solid
  +rem('height', 70px)

  @include susy-grid-background

  @include at-breakpoint($mobile-to-medium $columns-medium $medium-to-large)
    @include susy-grid-background

  @include at-breakpoint($medium-to-large)
    @include susy-grid-background

   .logo
     float: left
     border: 1px red solid
     +rem('margin', 20px 0)
     +data-uri-bg('logo.png')

   nav
     float: right
     +rem('margin', 20px 0)
     font-weight: 600
     @include at-breakpoint($mobile-to-medium $columns-medium)
       border: 1px blue solid
       @include span-columns(2)
       .tour
         display: none

       .action
         border: 1px green solid
         @include span-columns(1)
```

This maps to the following rendered layout:

[image]

Now, the effect of the `span-columns` does not seem to take effect, as well as the spacing from `.logo` to `nav`. I would like to have `.action` and the `.find` tags having width of 1 column each on the right, while the `.logo` has a fixed width on the left. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

The screen settings with Susy are:

```
$mobile-to-medium: 400px
$medium-to-large:  800px

$columns-small:    1
$columns-medium:   8
$columns-large:    12

$column-width   : 3em            // each column is 4em wide
$gutter-width   : 0.4em            // 1em gutters between columns
$grid-padding   : 0              // grid-padding equal to gutters

$total-columns: $columns-small
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to reset the column at the breakpoint. I don't know what's the value of your `mobile-to-medium`, `columns-medium`, `medium-to-large`, and `total-columns`. It's an important information that's not listed above. But you might want to check this one [Changing from 4 to 3 columns with omega with Susy fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938785/changing-from-4-to-3-columns-with-omega-with-susy-fails), I think that's related to your question.

Comment: thanks, I will try some experiments with: http://susy.oddbird.net/guides/reference/#ref-remove-omega ... btw, anyone has some reference what this 'omega' means?

Comment: that `omega` means the last element. So that element will be `float right` and no `margin` applied.